# Can't send data extract from Selenium to Excel using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create an excel file with the data from the Item List (informationn about the company name, title of the job and so on) extracted from a website. So, I am using the OPENXML library to put this data to Excel but it is not working. All I got is an excel file empty with anything. What is the problem??

```js
using JobWebScraper.Model;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace JobWebScraper.Driver
{
    public class AutomationWeb
    {
        public IWebDriver driver;

        public AutomationWeb()
        {
            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(); //vai abrir o navegador do Chrome
        }
         
        public DataTable TestWeb()
        {

            var dataTable = new DataTable();

            var items = new List<Item>();

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://br.indeed.com/");

            // Prompt user for input
            Console.WriteLine("Bem vindo ao JobSearcher");
            Console.WriteLine("Digite qual área você procura: ");
            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Trabalho remoto? S/N");
            string remoteInput = Console.ReadLine();


            // Use an explicit wait for the search input field to be clickable and then send keys
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            // Wait for the search input field to be clickable and then send keys
            IWebElement searchInput = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"text-input-what\"]")));

            // Send keys using the user input
            searchInput.SendKeys(userInput);
            searchInput.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);


            // remote work

            // Check if the answer for "Trabalho remoto? S/N" is 'S'
            if (remoteInput.ToUpper() == "S")
            {
                IWebElement locationInput = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("text-input-where")));

                // Clear any existing text using the "Delete" key
                locationInput.SendKeys(Keys.End); // Move the cursor to the end of the text
                locationInput.SendKeys(Keys.Shift + Keys.Home); // Select the entire text
                locationInput.SendKeys(Keys.Delete); // Delete the selected text


                locationInput.SendKeys("remoto");
                locationInput.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

                // Locate the all the jobs
                IWebElement allJobs = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"mosaic-provider-jobcards\"]/ul"));

                // Get all li elements within the ul
                var eachJob = allJobs.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));

                IWebElement closeGooglePopup = null;
                IWebElement closePopup = null;

                try
                {
                    closeGooglePopup = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"google-Only-Modal\"]/div/div[1]/button")));
                    closePopup = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"mosaic-desktopserpjapopup\"]/div[1]/button")));
                }
                catch (NoSuchElementException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Element not found or clickable");
                }

                if (closePopup != null)
                {
                    closeGooglePopup.Click();
                    closePopup.Click();
                }


                // Create DataTable columns
                dataTable.Columns.Add("Nome da Empresa");
                dataTable.Columns.Add("Titulo");
                dataTable.Columns.Add("Data");
                dataTable.Columns.Add("Link");


                foreach (var job in eachJob)
                {
                    var item = new Item();

                    foreach (var titleElement in job.FindElements(By.CssSelector("span[title]")))
                    {
                        // Access the title attribute for each element
                        string title = titleElement.GetAttribute("title");

                        // Add the title to the list
                        item.Titles.Add(title);


                        var companyNameElement = titleElement.FindElement(By.XPath("ancestor::li/descendant::span[@data-testid='company-name']"));

                        var publishedElement = titleElement.FindElement(By.XPath("ancestor::li/descendant::span[@class='date']"));

                        // Localizar todas as tags <a> com a classe 'jcs-JobTitle'
                        var joblinkElements = job.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a.jcs-JobTitle"));

                        Console.WriteLine($"Vaga: {title}, Empresa: {companyNameElement.Text}, Data: {publishedElement.Text}");


                        foreach (var joblinkElement in joblinkElements)
                        {
                            // Obter o valor do atributo href
                            string jobLink = joblinkElement.GetAttribute("href");

                            item.JobLinks.Add(jobLink);

                            Console.WriteLine($"- {jobLink}");

                        }


                        // Add the item to the items list
                        items.Add(new Item
                        {
                            CompanyName = companyNameElement.Text,
                            PublishDate = publishedElement.Text,
                        });
                    }

                }

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    dataTable.Rows.Add(item.CompanyName, item.PublishDate, item.Titles, item.JobLinks);
                }


                return dataTable;

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Trabalho presencial? S/N");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Onde?");
                return null; // Adding a return statement for non-'S' inputs

            }


        }

    }
}
```

```js
using System;
using System.Data;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using JobWebScraper.Driver;
using JobWebScraper.Model;
using OpenXmlCell = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell;
using OpenXmlRow = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row;



namespace JobWebScraper
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var web = new AutomationWeb();
            var dataTable = web.TestWeb();

            if (dataTable != null)
            {
                CreateExcel(dataTable);
            }
        }


        public static void CreateExcel(System.Data.DataTable dataTable)
        {
            var fileName = "VagasParaAlegrarSeuDia.xlsx";

            // Create a spreadsheet document
            using (var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(fileName, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
                workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

                var worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

                var sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
                sheets.AppendChild(new Sheet
                {
                    Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
                    SheetId = 1,
                    Name = "Jobs Data"
                });

                var sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

                // Add headers
                var headerRow = new Row();

                foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
                {
                    headerRow.AppendChild(new Cell(new CellValue(column.ColumnName)));
                }

                sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

                // Add data
                foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    var newRow = new Row();

                    foreach (var value in dataRow.ItemArray)
                    {
                        // Construct the cell
                        var cell = new Cell(new CellValue(value.ToString()));
                        newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                    }

                    sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
                }

                // Save changes
                workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Excel file created successfully.");
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: No new sheets also? Try also with "worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save()"

Comment: @Emanuele nope. I tried your solution, but it still not working :/

Comment: I tried Console.WriteLine in the rows like this " Console.WriteLine("Row data: " + string.Join(", ", dataRow.ItemArray)); "
And it gives this error in the jobLink: 
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Comment: I prefer NPOI myself, but for OpenXML I would check the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cell?view=openxml-2.8.1  (They're defining the cell with parameters and values first... then appending it to the new row, then appending the row to the worksheet.  You'll be iterating to append rows and cells to the worksheet...  after iterating and creating the whole worksheet.  set that to the worksheetpart...

Comment: @pcalkins sorry, I couldn't understand well. Can you show me what you trying to say, please?

Comment: you're doing this:  var cell = new Cell(new CellValue(value.ToString()));  That doesn't set the location or type... the example at microsoft.com shows this:  Cell cell = new Cell()   
                { CellReference = "A1", DataType = CellValues.String,  
                    CellValue = new CellValue("Microsoft") };   (it's setting location to A1 and it's DataType to string... as well as setting the cell's value to "Microsoft".)

Comment: I think you are also missing the bits that add the sheet: worksheet.Append(sheetData);  
            worksheetPart.Worksheet = worksheet;   Not familiar with OpenXML though... (NPOI is a little easier to deal with...)

Comment: @pcalkins I think I'll change my code to the NPOI library. OpenXML has been very difficult, especially for me as a beginner. Do you follow any NPOI documentation?

Comment: Check here for NPOI documentation:  https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi/wiki/Getting-Started-with-NPOI

Comment: ohhh, I did a last try using the OpenXML, and it worked haha. When I added the worksheet.Append(sheetData) it worked